# "The man was either mad or both"

Tags: meaning, jokes, puns

In the delightful Fry and Laurie sketch *The Letter*, several puns are expertly delivered by Stephen Fry, however there is one I don't understand. [At 4:45 in the video](http://youtu.be/e9YcWLqjb9k?t=4m45s), he says "The man was either mad, or both", and it seems this should be funny, but I don't get it. Where is the pun in this sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize this question is quite old, but I disagree with an earlier answer.
While Stephen Fry's delivery is brilliant comedy in itself, there's also some word-play going on here.

The term **mad** can mean either angry or crazy. So here he's saying the man was either [meaning of] mad, or both; i.e. either angry or crazy or both.

Comment: Yep, not only does "mad" have two senses, but so does "either".

Answer (score 4):

The 'funny' comes from the fact that he should have said '*The man was either mad **or X** or both*'. You can see that he looks at the book for the 'or X' that he may have missed.

Comment: Oh. I was sure I was missing some sort of wordplay which made it funny.

Comment: @5xum There is a lot of clever word play in there, that wasn't one of them. I'm not sure what sort of gag that is but it's quite common, maybe **a double take** where the person delivering the line has to check that what they said was right.